# Как объяснить, что предложение составлено неверно?

Tags: грамматика

Не помню правила, трудно объяснить, что предложение составлено неграмотно. А мне доказывают, что все верно. "Наступив на очередную ветку, она неожиданно разломилась на две части." Имеется ввиду ветка разломилась))

Comment: Грамматически предложение выражает такой "смысл": наступившая на ветку неназванная барышня разломилась пополам. Абсурдность этого высказывания и могла бы убедить автора в неправильности написанного.

Comment: @Alex_ander *Грамматически предложение выражает такой "смысл"* - оно, конечно, так, но грамматически про барышню ничего нету. "Она" - может быть зверем, предметом или вообще абстракцией, лишь бы женского рода. Ну или собственно веткой. Вы домыслили грамматику.

Comment: Грамматика здесь подходит только к  _живому существу_, способному _наступить на ветку_ (поэтому не всякая абстрация). Пусть это будет куница, но в реальном мире она не "разламывается пополам".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, неправильно.
А правила тут особого-то и нету. Деепричастие в современном русском языке описывает действие того же субъекта, что и основной глагол. Это понятийно, без претензий на точность. Ветка, получается, сама на себя наступила?

Ну а если хотите более академических формулировок, смотрите, например, здесь.
https://7lafa.com/answer/12907
Источник нельзя назвать авторитетным, но все разложено по полочкам.